# In OpenOffice Calc, how do I drag and drop cells to insert rather than replace their destination?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I want to rearrange rows with the mouse in Calc.

In Excel, I select the whole row, then drag and drop it while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This causes the drag and drop cursor to turn into a bar rather than cells, and the cells are inserted at the bar's position.

Is there a way to accomplish the same sort of thing in Calc without going around the houses inserting columns before the drag operation?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a way to move whole columns using the mouse like in Excel:

- To move:  press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, then left click somewhere in the 
  selected column (not the column header) and drag.
- To copy:  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>, then left click somewhere in the 
  selected column (not the column header) and drag.

---

Tested with OpenOffice 3.2 Calc, Windows XP.

Comment: Aha, that does insert rather than replace, thanks!
But maybe there's a bug on OS X, as the original is left behind.

Comment: Worked for me - at least with the NeoOffice variant of OO. Opt-dragging dropped a copy of the source column and Ctrl-Opt-drag moved the column.

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter said, for moving columns you have to left click somewhere in the selected column (not on the column header) and drag. Now you can press some modifier keys:

- no modifiers: move columns, overwriting the destination
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>: copy columns, overwriting the destination
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>: move columns, inserting them between other columns
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>: copy columns, inserting them between other columns

Tested with OpenOffice.org 4.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Just downloaded the latest version today, and using Alt still copies rather than moves. I'm on OS X.